# Loading resources with require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to load or resources in my header with require.js. How can i do this? Here is my current code for my controller and index. I am new to angularjs and will appreciate your help in solving this challenge.

Require.js: located in js/require.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",    
    paths: {
        'angular': '.../lib/angular.min',
        'angular-route': '.../lib/angular-route.min',
        'angularAMD': '.../lib/angular-animate.min.js'
    },
    shim: { 'angular-animate.min': ['angular'], 'angular-route': ['angular'] },
    deps: ['app']
    });
```

Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>App Demo</title>
 <script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
 <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main" ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js:

```
define(function () {
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'artistControllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
when('/list', {
templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
controller: 'ListContrIndex.htmloller'
}).
when('/details/:itemId', {
templateUrl: 'partials/details.html',
controller: 'DetailsController'
}).
otherwise({
redirectTo: '/list'
});
}]);
  return app;
  });
```

Controller.js:

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
var artistControllers = angular.module('artistControllers', ['ngAnimate']);

artistControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
$scope.artists = data;
$scope.artistOrder = 'name';
});
}]);

artistControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
$http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
$scope.artists = data;
$scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;

if ($routeParams.itemId > 0) {
  $scope.prevItem = Number($routeParams.itemId)-1;
} else {
  $scope.prevItem = $scope.artists.length-1;
}

if ($routeParams.itemId < $scope.artists.length-1) {
  $scope.nextItem = Number($routeParams.itemId)+1;
} else {
  $scope.nextItem = 0;
}

});
}]);
```

});

Comment: <script data-main="scripts/main" src="js/require.js"></script>     add this

Comment: this sample code may guide you http://embed.plnkr.co/Mk2qHB8zUB28PDViNjv4/

Answer (score 0):

use `data-main="path/file.js"` to specify the file to load scripts..

`<script data-main="path/file.js" src="js/require.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>App Demo</title>
 <script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main" ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in main.js

```
    require.config({
        baseUrl: "js",    
        paths: {
            'angular': '.../lib/angular.min',
            'angular-route': '.../lib/angular-route.min',
            'angularAMD': '.../lib/angular-animate.min.js'
        },
        shim: { 'angular-animate.min': ['angular'], 'angular-route': ['angular'] },
        deps: ['app']
        });

require(['requireModule,'requireModule2'],function(requireModule,requireModule2){
//code to start the application
})
```

Your code doesn't allow to start the application through requirejs . You need to [define AngularJS Components as RequireJS Modules](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/)

Comment: check my corrected code. What is still the problem?

Comment: did you create the main.js file ?

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS loads all code relative to a baseUrl. The baseUrl is normally set to the same directory as the script used in a data-main attribute for the top level script to load for a page. The data-main attribute is a special attribute that require.js will check to start script loading. This example will end up with a baseUrl of scripts:

```
<!--This sets the baseUrl to the "scripts" directory, and
loads a script that will have a module ID of 'main'-->
<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/require.js"/>
```

For more information on this, check [Loading JS Files - Require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles)